# toggle select based on data-depth

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<select id="advert_category" name="advert_category">
<option value="">All Items</option>
<option value="512">All Test 2</option>
<option value="52">Vehicles</option>
<option value="64" data-depth="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Cars For Sale</option>
<option value="65" data-depth="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Cars For Rent</option>
<option value="66" data-depth="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;All Vehicle Spare Parts</option>
<option value="67" data-depth="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;Number</option>
</select>
```

on document load all subcategories should be hidden once the user presses on parent category it should toggle related subcategories.
How can I do this using jquery?

Comment: So what have  you tried so far to achieve that?

Comment: nth its not working

Comment: $(this).find('[data-depth=1]').toggle();
is toggling all suncategories of all categories

Answer (score 0):

You can use classes (or even [HTML data-* Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)) for this and extract them on click of parent, then condition this to show subcategories.

When you click on Vehicles for example with `class="Vehicles"` it will get `Vehicles` from it in variable `classes`.
Then you find all classes with `Vehicles-option` and do something with it.

```
find("."+classes+"-option")
```

```js
$( "#advert_category > option" ).click(function() {
var classes=$(this).attr("class");
console.log(classes);
$("#advert_category").find("."+classes+"-option").toggle();
});
```

```css
.Vehicles-option, .colors-option {
display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="advert_category" name="advert_category">
<option value="">All Items</option>
<option value="512">All Test 2</option>
<option value="52" class="Vehicles">Vehicles</option>
<option value="64" data-depth="1" class="Vehicles-option" hidden>&nbsp;&nbsp;Cars For Sale</option>
<option value="65" data-depth="1" class="Vehicles-option"  >&nbsp;&nbsp;Cars For Rent</option>
<option value="66" data-depth="1" class="Vehicles-option" hidden>&nbsp;&nbsp;All Vehicle Spare Parts</option>
<option value="67" data-depth="1" class="Vehicles-option"  >&nbsp;&nbsp;Number</option>
<option value="52" class="colors">Colors</option>
<option value="64" data-depth="1" class="colors-option"  >&nbsp;&nbsp;Red</option>
<option value="65" data-depth="1" class="colors-option" >&nbsp;&nbsp;Blue</option>
</select>
```

Aldo I have to say this seems like bad design as user must click again to show those subcategory, but that is what you wanted. Maybe rahter implement hover and see how that beehives. And please see [HTML optgroup Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/tag_optgroup.asp).

BTW, you can not just keep select item open after clicking, so your toggle wont work as I think you want it to work:

[Open Select using Javascript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048213/open-select-using-javascript-jquery)

[jQuery simulate click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316272/jquery-simulate-click)

[Make html select option drop down menu open by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827047/make-html-select-option-drop-down-menu-open-by-default)