# How to trigger a <select> to expand (like it does after a mouse click)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to open up the `<select>` list that a browser renders upon a regular click from a `<button>`.

I tried

```
const select = document.querySelector('select');
select.click();
```

Nothing happens. With `.focus()` I get the result I would expect from iOS, but not on Chrome or Android.

## Edit

I specifically want to trigger the platform native `<select>` picker, not a custom built thing.

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, but you can create your own list component and do it with that.

Comment: This seems to work in https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-spence-m7kt9. Is the select you want to open the first select in the dom?

Comment: @CharlesBamford I changed your code to reflect my situation, and it doesn't work. https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-night-f8cdu

Comment: I see now, Scott's right that this isn't possible. Instead of implementing your own select list you could use a select library like https://github.hubspot.com/select/docs/welcome/

Comment: If you are comfortable with using a library, you can try Bootstrap Selectpicker: https://jsfiddle.net/pj8hftyg/

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048213/open-select-using-javascript-jquery

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316272/jquery-simulate-click

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827047/make-html-select-option-drop-down-menu-open-by-default